# Problem with fluid simulation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Can anyone explain me why the ball falls into the water withour making any wave and why the inflow doesn't emit water?

[image]

Comment: My domain was not activated in view and render mode.

Answer (score 0):

you set "effector" to your "eau" which should be Flow/liquid/geometry.

Raise resolution to 64 in your domain.

If you bake again, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Ok, "eau" should be Flow/Liquid/Geometry. But water should flow out of "robinet", which is Flow/Liquid/inflow, and, strangely, changing "eau" parameter and baking again hasn't provided any improvement.

Comment: i updated my answer. Raise resolution in domain to 64.

Comment: Well, not better... Increasing to 128 doesn't help either.

Comment: what blender version do u use? can u pls provide updated blend file?

Comment: I use Blender version 3.2.0. File updated.